# Как использовать urllib2 вместо requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests

Вот такой код:

```
import requests
requestpost = requests.post(url2, data={'key': key, 'text': last_chat_text, 'lang': lang})
response_data = requestpost.json()
print(response_data.items())
```

Comment: Ну, прочитать документацию и использовать согласно документации?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по Вашему коду, вопрос про Python 3.

Вот такой код:

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse
import json

url2 = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts'
key = last_chat_text = lang = None

data = urllib.parse.urlencode({'key': key, 'text': last_chat_text, 'lang': lang})
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url2, data.encode()).read().decode()
response_data = json.loads(response)

print(response_data.items())
```

Только имейте в виду, если сервер отдаёт redirect, то запрос проредиректится, но это уже будет GET запрос, а не POST.